# Understanding non-homogeneous numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have recently started numpy and noticed a peculiar thing.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,9, 8]])
print a.shape, "shape"
print a[1, 0]
```

The shape, in this case, comes out to be `2L`. However if I make a homogenous numpy array as 
`a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]`, then `a.shape` gives `(2L, 3L)`. I understand that the shape of a non-homogenous array is difficult to represent as a tuple.

Additionally, `print a[1,0]` for non-homogenous array that I created earlier gives a traceback `IndexError: too many indices for array`. Doing the same on the homogenous array gives back the correct element `4`.

Noticing these two peculiarities, I am curious to know how python looks at non-homogenous numpy arrays at a low level. 
Thank You in advance

Comment: What you made in the first case is a 1-dimensional array with data type object (and the items stored in the array are python lists). Hence the shape. It's still a homogeneous array from Numpy's point of view (as it doesn't "see" or care what the objects are or what's "inside" them), unless I'm misunderstanding the designation.

Comment: In numpy 1.13, this will be more obvious, and the array will render as `array([list([1,2,3]), list([4,5,9,8])])`

Comment: @blubberdiblub I get the homogeneous part. It was the non-homogeneous part that was intriguing me. Thank you for the comment

Comment: Thank You @Eric. Does that mean non-homogeneous arrays will be slower when involved in computations compared to homogeneous arrays? I understand that the "constant size" of each element immensely decides the speed advantage.

Comment: @0Nicholas The vectorized operations will not even work the same for arrays of objects (that are lists). As Numpy tries to apply the operations on the objects (not the contents of the objects). Thus, you cannot even sensibly measure the performance difference, as the results are different. Just try `a.sum()` on your array of objects from the question. It will yield a concatenated list instead of the sum of all inner elements.

Comment: Now that you say it, it seems intuitive. Thank you @blubberdiblub. I am getting a better picture of numpy now.

Comment: @0Nicholas I would probably call it confusing and a mistake, that `np.array()` even accepts inputs like that. It would be a lot better if it required to specify `dtype=object` in that case, so it could be sure of the intention of the coder. I. e. in my own book `np.array([[1,2], [3,4,5]])` would throw an exception, whereas `np.array([[1,2], [3,4,5]], dtype=object)` would work the same way as you have shown above.

Comment: Yes, it does seem a bit confusing but I think it allows for simplicity as well. I mean, once you have it at the back of the mind how a non-homogeneous array is going to work, it will be very annoying to write `dtype=object` every single time. I think, it may even be a bit non-Pythonic.

Comment: @0Nicholas well, my point is I wouldn't even use arrays like that if I can help it. Numpy arrays of objects should be rather rare. After all, most of Numpy's power lies in its vectorized operations on arrays of numbers. If you really need an array where some values are "missing", you would use masked arrays rather than arrays of objects (lists).

Comment: @blubberdiblub Indeed, you have a valid point. In my little experience, I am unable to think of an application of numpy arrays of objects. Do you know of any such application?

Comment: @0Nicholas not off-hand, no. Maybe if you have some objects that are arranged in a 2-dimensional grid (or higher dimensional) and you want an easy way to select sub-grids or transpose that grid. That's also one of Numpy's strength (operations regarding multi-dimensional subscripts) and is thus easier than when done on foot with Python looping constructs.

Comment: @blubberdiblub that would be at the expense of speed, right?

Comment: @0Nicholas if the arrays are large, no. (There's some overhead involved when using Numpy, which when the arrays are small can make it slower than non-Numpy operations. But that's easily amortized once the arrays get larger.) I was just talking about operations on the grid itself. I. e. Numpy doesn't go into the objects. It just shuffles the **references** to the objects around. And often it doesn't even need to do that, as it makes use of views when it can. And you cannot generally do a `sum()` on custom Python objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the sublists differ in length, `np.array` falls back to creating an `object dtype` array:

```
In [272]: a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,9, 8]])
In [273]: a
Out[273]: array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 9, 8]], dtype=object)
```

This array is similar to the list we started with.  Both store the sublists as pointers.  The sublists exist else where in memory.

With equal length sublsts, it can create a 2d array, with integer elements:

```
In [274]: a2 = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,9]])
In [275]: a2
Out[275]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 9]])
```

In fact to confirm my claim that the sublists are stored elsewhere in memory, let's try to change one:

```
In [276]: alist = [[1,2,3], [4,5,9, 8]]
In [277]: a = np.array(alist)
In [278]: a
Out[278]: array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 9, 8]], dtype=object)
In [279]: a[0].append(4)
In [280]: a
Out[280]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 9, 8]], dtype=object)
In [281]: alist
Out[281]: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 9, 8]]
```

That would not work in the case of `a2`.  `a2` has its own data storage, independent of the source list.

The basic point is that `np.array` tries to create an n-d array where possible.  If it can't it falls back on to creating an object dtype array.  And, as has been discussed in other questions, it sometimes raises an error.  It is also tricky to intentionally create an object array.

The shape of `a` is easy, (2,). A single element tuple.  `a` is a 1d array.  But that shape does not convey information about the elements of `a`.  And the same goes for the elements of `alist`.  `len(alist)` is 2.  An object array can have a more complex shape, e.g. `a.reshape(1,2,1)`, but it is still just contains pointers

`a` contains 2 4byte pointers; `a2` contains 6 4byte integers.

```
n [282]: a.itemsize
Out[282]: 4
In [283]: a.nbytes
Out[283]: 8
In [284]: a2.nbytes
Out[284]: 24
In [285]: a2.itemsize
Out[285]: 4
```

Comment: Thank You. That makes a lot of sense.